# Does QM talk about reality in itself or our observation of it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers, quantum-interpretations, superposition, observables

I am not a physicist and I've recently started watching introductory lectures on QM on youtube (MIT, Stanford) and reading the Feynman lectures. I have a high-school level knowledge of Math so I'm not good (yet?) with equations. I'm pointing this out because I'm looking for answer that will not rely on Math to prove its/make a point.

I've read about the double slit experiment, superposition and the idea that at a quantum level, a particle can "be" at two opposing states at the same time etc.

What confuses me is that lecturers seem to use words like "is" and "is measured/observed to be" interchangeably.

So my question is this: are QM physicists saying that this is how nature literally is, in itself and by itself, ***a priori***, regardless of any possible observation by us humans, or are they saying that this is how reality is ***observed*** to behave/be at a quantum level.

In other words, are they open to the possibility that things like superposition might turn out, in the future, to *not literally be the case* but that they were just an "illusion" of observation perpetuated at the time due to our limited observational/computational capabilities at the time (or even vice versa, I'm fine with that as well)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about philosophy of knowledge and natural science in general, not physics in particular. To what degree a physicist believes that physical theories reflect "how the world really is", and whether reality as distinct from what we observe is a meaningful notion or not, are philosophical beliefs not inherent in the bare physical theory - this is literal *meta*physics.

Comment: Furthermore, for quantum mechanics in particular, there are plenty of different [interpretations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics), so the assumption of this question that "QM physicists" have a unified viewpoint of the ontology underlying QM is simply wrong, and it cannot be answered as posed.

Comment: _are they open to the possibility that things like superposition might turn out, in the future, to not literally be the case but that they were just an "illusion"_ What you are talking about is **hidden variables** theory, which was already disproved. So, yes, it was considered by scientists, but proved that this possibility will never happen in future. And yes, nature behaves so at quantum level, by "observation" we mean **any** interaction with superimposed system of particle(s). Decoherence may happen by reasons not involved with humans at all, or even spontaneously.

Comment: You've basically answered my question so I'm fine with closing it. "For physicists what is observed and measured is what is, so talking about anything else is irrelevant". It is definitely somewhat irrelevant to the progress of science but also definitely naive to think that this is the case. That is why the universe managed to survive and continue to be even without humans observing it.

Comment: @SproutCoder You should have stayed with your first question. Of course you should be open to the idea that superposition  does not turn out to be the case. It calculates without explaining and Definitely does not represent a physical model of anything. We know something is physically happening and superposition does not explain that part. So obviously it will turn out to not be the case.